# Watir/Selenium - cannot reach injected Angular page elements

Tags: angular, ruby, selenium, web-scraping, watir

I have to test website which is written in Angular (*ng-* html tags are present) with Watir (which is a Ruby gem based on Selenium). But the body of the page is somehow split into 'static' html and 'dynamic' html, probably injected by Angular. My Chrome browser calls it frame and allows me to check html for this part separately like this:

[image]

Only 'static' html is reachable for Watir while 'dynamic' is not. Only way to check structure of those injected elements is by inspecting elements via Chrome console or by View frame source option as listed above.

For what I understand Angular injects this dynamic content here:

```
<div class="view" ui-view></div>
```

Waiting doesn't change anything. I've tried both ordinary **sleep** and **WatirAngular.wait_for_angular(browser)** (from watir-angular gem) but none of those options worked for me. It's seems like this part of the page is invisible for my browser object no matter how long I would wait.

Is it possible to make it somehow reachable?

Comment: If you're talking about the Shadow DOM, the browser drivers are currently working to add support for that functionality, but it doesn't exist yet. @justin-ko does this sound like something you were looking at recently?

Comment: @titusfortner thank you for your response. Where can I track latest updates on this topic?

Comment: The spec for it is here: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#shadow-root The issue is that the browser vendors need to implement it, not sure there is a way to track that at this point. We'll likely be discussing the status of it in our biweekly meetings (held on Slack and logged here: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/)

Comment: What is the Watir code you are using to locate the element? Watir needs to be explicitly told when to look for elements in the frame. For example, you should have something like `browser.frame(id: 'frame_identifier').div(id: 'div_identifier')`.

Comment: @titusfortner, yes I had been looking at adding shadow DOM support. Had Chrome working but Firefox had issues. Given you said drivers were already working on adding support, I had stopped. But if it will be a while, I can re-try getting things running.

Comment: @JustinKo From the Selenium side, Jim added the code in .NET last week, and Simon just added code for it in Java, so there is pressure from the Selenium devs for browser vendors to get it working. David was working on it for Firefox, but I think it got held up for some reason and is back in Mozilla's hands. Really not sure the timeframe for when we get something, but hopefully "soon."

Comment: @Justin Ko you said It's working for Chrome, eh? Can you please provide us the solution?